# Adjust axes in Plot3D as python do

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to compare same plot with mathematica and python but they use different order of axes. I tried to change them in `Plot3D` such that they look like the following plot in python:
[image]
but lot of tricks did not work. Namely I tried `AxesEdge`, `AxesOrigin`, `ViewPoint`, $\ldots$ etc.

Is there any simple way to do this avoiding dynamic and rotation ?

I'm using the following code

```
domain = {0, 1};
Plot3D[Exp[x y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, ##}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
PlotLegends -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}] & @@ domain
```

It gives the following:
[image]

Comment: Does `Graphics3D[{}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, FaceGrids -> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, PlotRange -> ConstantArray[{0, 1}, 3], ViewPoint -> {-2.4, -2.4, 2.}]` look like what you need?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm using `Plot3D` and z-axis is in the right side linked to x-axis as in the image.

Comment: Copy the `AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}`, `FaceGrids -> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}`, and `ViewPoint -> {-2.4, -2.4, 2.}` into your `Plot3D[]` and see if it helps.

Comment: It gives x and y with same origin and z on the left hand side. I got the same result with `AxesEdge`. In my case, x and z are with same origin and y start at the end of x-axis.

Comment: Can you please include the `Plot3D[]` expression you are having trouble with, then? It's hard to say anything more helpful without seeing something concrete.

Comment: I've edited the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you need?:

```
domain = {0, 1};
Plot3D[Exp[x y], {y, ##}, {x, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic,
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", "Reverse"}, AxesEdge -> {Automatic, {1, -1}, {1, 1}},
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed"] & @@ domain
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, just x and y are reversed.

Comment: @Migalobe That's easy to modify, see my update.

Comment: I think it's like we plot $f(y,x)$ instead of $f(x,y)$. They are not the same if the function is not symmetric, right ?

Comment: @Migalobe No, I'm just changing the order of axis. Remember that 2nd argument of `Plot3D` is the range for _1st_ axis (usually denoted as $x$ axis in traditional math. )

Comment: Thank you. When specifying the `PlotRange` to `PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0.5}, {0, 110}}` I get a flat view. Is this normal ?

Comment: @Migalobe Of course, `110` is so large compared to the maximum of `Exp[x y]` in the plotted domain.